# Table of a two variable function

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to generate a table using a function of two variables. I tried the following:

```
Table[{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}]
```

which does work as I had hoped. I want the table to produce `a, b, f[a, b]` in columns using `Grid`. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: `Table[{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}] // Grid` ?
`Table[{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}] // TableForm` ?

Comment: Thank you, these work, but table iterates a1 b1, F[a1,b1] then a1,b2,F[a1,b2] etc I would like a1,b1,F[a1,b1] then a2,b2,F[a2,b2].  Can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear how many columns that you want. Some of the possibilities

```
data = Table[{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}];

data // Flatten[#, 1] & // Grid
```

[image]

```
Row[Riffle[Grid /@ Partition[data // Flatten[#, 1] &, 18], Spacer[25]]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Riffle[Grid /@ Partition[data // Flatten[#, 1] &, 12], 
  Spacer[25]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm not used to this site and did not realize that Bob Hanion has given me a good answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user3429864: I'm confused - you accepted an answer which gives a result  different from what you said you wanted in your comment responding to mine on your original post. By contrast, corey979's answer does give what you said in that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Judging [from your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133249/table-of-a-two-variable-function#comment359427_133249), you want this:

```
MapThread[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}] // Grid
```

[image]

---

Or if the `a`'s and `b`'s take the same corresponding values:

```
Table[{a, a, f[a, a]}, {a, 1, 5}] // Grid
```

[image]