# Export .dat file of a function with two varialbles

Tags: export, list-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have a function `j*sin[i]`, I would like to generate a data set.
 I tried using

```
Table[{i,j,j*sin[i]},{i,-10,10,0.5},{j,-10,10,0.5}]
```

I would like to get the output in three columns: `x`, `v`, and `j*sin[i]`

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Mathematica, all the built-in functions start with a capital letter. So, `sin` should be `Sin[]`. To get three columns `Flatten` it down to level 1. `Flatten[Table[{i,j,j*sin[i]},{i,-10,10,0.5},{j,-10,10,0.5}],1]`. Then, use `Export[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table of a two variable function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133249/table-of-a-two-variable-function)

Comment: Check here please: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Anjan Kumar, you can do it like this,

```
f[i_, j_] := j*Sin[i];
data = Flatten[Table[{i, j, N[f[i, j]]}, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 3}], 1];
TableForm[%, TableHeadings -> {None, {"i", "j", "j*Sin[i]"}}]
```

[image]

```
Export["C:/tcdata/myfile.dat", data, "Table"]
```

Comment: The question is badly phrased, and I also misunderstood it.  But after reading the *title*, I do not think this is what he is asking.

Comment: @Szabolcs You maybe right but three columns made me think that the OP wants `i`, `j` and `jSin[i]`. Lets wait and see for his response.

Comment: Thank you sir.... thanks a lot for your suggestion. But I need the file in a different format. I mean like a  matrix

Comment: @HariKrishnan Any example? It might help to understand your question.

Comment: Sir I mean that, In the answer given above, i want the file to be written as                    values of i is written as a row and values of j will be  written  as a column and the value of the function will be represented accordingly. Hence i and j forming an index for the matrix formed by function

Comment: i would like to add a pic so it you will be able to understand it properly

Comment: @HariKrishnan I don't understand. Show me an example